# Finding the type of the first letter of the value of a JavaScript variable, whether it is a letter, a number or a special character

Tags: javascript

I've a variable named var `text = 'Saif'`

So how can I check the first character of this value (S) is a letter, number or special character??

I've already tried with the code bellow -

```
var text                = 'Saif'
var char                = /[A-Z]/g
var num                 = /[0-9]/g

if (text.match(char)) {
    console.log("The string starts with Letter")
} else if (text.match(num)){
    console.log("The string starts with Number")
} else {
    console.log("The string starts with Special character")
}
```

It's working fine with the condition of letter and number. But I can't being able to find the special character instead of letter or number.

How can I do that?

Comment: ```/[^A-Z0-9]/g```?

Comment: I've tried with this. But still being mess there with this expression. -_- @ajarrow

Comment: Your title and your code made me confuse... you wrote: "first character value" and you are checking all the value, if you want only the first character you need to to `text[0]` in this way it works fine

Comment: @tomerraitz it won't show \    if the text  is `\hello` ..it shows only `h`

Comment: `!text.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9]/)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var text                = 's2Saif'
var char                = /^[A-Z]/g
var num                 = /^\d/g

if (text.match(char)) {
    console.log("The string starts with Letter")
} else if (text.match(num)){
    console.log("The string starts with Number")
} else {
    console.log("The string starts with Special character")
}
```

Does Letter contain lowercase character? If so, let `var char = /^\w/g;`

Comment: I don't want to find lowercase or uppercase character anymore. I just want to find is it a special character or not like (@#$%&*-+"':;/=^{}

Comment: Please post it in a new question

Comment: @Saifullah: then either ask a new question (to avoid the answers here being penalised because you asked the wrong question) or edit the question here (and explain very carefully that invalid answers are answering the question you originally asked, which was the wrong question). Next time, please take the time to ask the question you want to ask and try not to change your mind midway through.

Comment: `!text.match(/^[(@#$%&*\-+"':;\/=^{}]/)`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>First of all, `char` is a reserved word in JavaScript - best not to use it in your variable names.</strike>

Secondly, if you want to test a pattern but not actually retrieve the match, use `test()` rather than `match()`.

Thirdly, your current patterns don't enforce only the *first* character of the string; they allow *any* character within it.

```
if (/^[a-z]/ig.test(text))
    console.log("The string starts with Letter")
else if (/^\d/.test(text))
    console.log("The string starts with Number")
else
    console.log("The string starts with Special character")
```

Comment: [There is no reserved keyword `char` in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords)

Comment: Interesting - I felt sure it used to be. Indeed, various online resources still list it as reserved.

Comment: This fails when the name is `Şaif`. But don't know if that's a problem for OP.

Comment: @Mitya your code is working now. Thank you. Thank you very much.

Comment: @michel Fails how? It identifies it (correctly) as a special character.

Comment: @Mitya For me `á é Ü Ş` etc are letters, not special characters. It's a letter with a diacritic.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
var format = /[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/;

// This ↓ method will return true or false value.
if (format.test(text)) {

     console.log("The string starts with Special character");

}
```